# Using auto-number database fields theory

Tags: ms-access-2010, auto-increment

I was on "another" programming forum, and we were talking about getting the next number from an auto-increment field BEFORE an insert takes place (there is a way using ADOX). This was in an MS-Access database btw.

Anyway, the discussion veered off into the area of SHOULD you use auto-increment fields for things like invoice numbers, PO numbers, bill of lading numbers, or anything else that needs an unique, incrementing number.

My thoughts were "why not"? Other people are arguing that an Invoice number (for instance) should be managed as a separate table and incremented with code, not using an auto-number field.

Can someone give me a good reason why that would be true?
I've used auto-number fields for years for just this type of thing and have never had problem one.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always avoided number auto_increment.  As it turns out for good reason. But originally my reasons were because that was what the professor told us.

Facebook had a major breach a few years ago - simply because they were use AUTO_INCREMENT fields for user id's.  Doesn't take a calculator to figure out that if my ID is 10320 there is likely someone with ID 10319, etc.

When debugging (or proofing design) having a key that implicit of the data it represents is a heck of a lot easier.

Have keys that are implicit of the data reduces the potencial for corrupted data (type's and user guessing).

Implicit keys require the developer think about they're data.  I have never come across a table using implicit keys that was not normalized.

Other than the fact deadlines often run tight - there is no great reason for auto increment.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I use and autonumbering field for the ID so I don't need to think about how's generated.

The recordset operation like insert and delete alter the sequence skipping block of numbers.

When you manage CustomerID, Invoice Numbers and so on, it's better to have the full control over them instead of letting them under system's control.

You can create a function that generates for you the desired numbers using a rule (e.g. the invoice can be a function that include the invoicing date).

With autonumbering you can't manage this.

After that there is NO FIXED RULES about what to do and what not do.
It's just your practice and experience and the degree of freedom you want to have.

Bye:-)